# I'm learning WCF and I'm stumped; why would I use this over a regular web service?

Tags: wcf

What benefits does WCF bring to the table and why should I use this new technology over good old ASP.Net web services?

Comment: @Sergio please stop tagging things as newbie. Use beginner instead. (this is like the 3rd question I retagged of yours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't need to transition to WCF if regular Web-Service will work for you,
however WCF encompasses more than just Web-Services.

With WCF you can utilize different communication channels (such as Web-Services, MSMQ, named pipes...) utilizing the same end-point service handler code.

WCF also has different built-in security mechanisms, allows you to utilize different serialization mechanisms (if something other than Soap is needed like raw JSON), hosting of services without the requirement of needing a web project etc...

As such WCF is more a general service hosting framework that can replace regular ASMX web services

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article from msdn that talks about the differences between ASMX and WCF

A few key areas

1. Serialization - Asmx uses XmlSerializer while WCF uses the DataContractSerializer.  The Datacontract serializer is about 10% faster (source along with other [information](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/))
   [Differences Between ASMX and WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304771.aspx)
2. Greater protocol support (HTTP, TCP, ICP, MSMQ for WCF), ASMX only supports HTTP